# Sequence with decreasing distances between elements: how to prove its Cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I am new to sequences and encountered a task where I am to show that a sequence $(a_n)$ that fulfills the following criteria is a Cauchy sequence.

$\forall n \geq 2 : |a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq L \cdot |a_n - a_{n-1}|$ with $0 \leq L < 1$.

This means that the following is true as well:

$|a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq L^n \cdot |a_1 - a_0|$

$\frac{|a_{n+1} - a_n|}{|a_1 - a_0|} \leq L^n$

Since $L^n$ converges to $0$ and we have the quotient of two absolutes, I can use the Squeeze theorem to conclude that the sequence $(a_n)$ converges to $0$ as well. Every convering sequence is a Cauchy sequence which concludes my proof.

However, I am really unsure because I also found sequences that look like they would fulfill the description but are not converging like this one:
[diverging sequence with decreasing difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvKQ4.png)

Where did I go wrong and how can I show that it is a Cauchy sequence?

I was made aware of a post dealing with the same problem and using Cantor's lemma: [Using Cantor's lemma in a proof of convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546542/using-cantors-lemma-in-a-proof-of-convergence)

However, I am not allowed to use Cantor's lemma for this task, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When you claim “that this sequence converges to $0$”, which sequence do you have in mind?

Comment: I guess any sequence that fulfills $\forall n \geq 2 : |a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq L \cdot |a_n - a_{n-1}|$. I will make that clearer in my post!